# Body as a readable stream nextjs api route

Tags: next.js

In the client I'm sending this axios path request:

```
  const handleSave = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.patch(`/api/mongo/users/${params.id}`, editedUser); // Use PATCH request to update specific fields
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating user:', error);
    }
  };
```

In the server side I have this haldler:

```
const PATCH = async (req, context) => {
  const { id } = context.params
  console.log('PATCH', id)
  const { body } = req
  console.log('PATCH', body)
  const results = await Users.updateOne({ _id: new ObjectId(id) }, body)
  return NextResponse.json(results)
}
```

export {PATCH}

the console.log('PATCH', body) displys this:

```
PATCH ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }
```

It's my first time with Nextjs 13.4 api routes. What is the right way to handle this request?

Answer (score 1):

I need to do:
const body = await req.json()
//then I can use body data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).